# CSS: Wrap whole blocks of text according to container width

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have some block of text like this:

```
<div>
    <span class="part-1">Some text.</span>
    <span class="part-2">Some text.</span>
</div>
```

Parent `div` element has fluid width. How to make two `span` elements to remain in one line if container is wide enough, to wrap them if there is not enough space, but to avoid wrapping inside `span` elements?

In other words, `.part-2` should be either in line with `.part-1` or below it, but always whole.

EDIT: Important part is that `.part-2` should not overflow the container, which happens if `white-space: no-wrap` is used.

Comment: Pretty sure that with the restrictions you have in place that this not possible.

Comment: That's what I was afraid to hear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<style>
    .unbreakable{
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #container{
        overflow:hidden;
    }

</style>

<div id="container">
    <span class="part-1 unbreakable">Some text.</span>
    <span class="part-2 unbreakable">Some text.</span>
</div>
```

Using the white-space css property, you can define how wrapping can occur inside elements. Using nowrap will prevent any wrapping on spaces.

EDIT: Added overflow hidden so the text doesn't go out. You could use scroll to add scrollbars.

Comment: Sorry, I tried 'white-space: no-wrap' already, but I forgot to say that I also need second block not to overflow the container :)

Comment: Edited. Care to explain more exactly what you'd want in your post please?

Comment: Sure. So, these are requirements: 
1. no overflow (no hidden, no scrollbars, no auto, no nothing)
2. span elements either inline or one below another, depending on parent's width
3. no wrapping inside span elements

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox maybe but you're still getting overflow.

Hmmm...

```css
div {
  margin: 40px auto;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-title {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-title > span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-title">
  <span class="part-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  <span class="part-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, enim!</span>
</div>
```